# Asynchronous image resizing with ImageMagick through a cron job / job queue

Tags: asynchronous, cron, imagemagick, thumbnails, image-resizing

This question focuses on finding a perfect solution for an asynchronous image resizing process guided by a cron job / job queue.

*Images are getting uploaded and saved in the original size on the server. The resize process picks them up, resizes and saves them in two new sizes. For this job I use Imagemagick with the following setup [nice -n 19 convert -density 500 "' . $fullpath . '" -resample ' . $dpi . ' "' . $destFolder . '/%d.jpg"']. "nice" will not prevent a command from using 100% CPU. What it does do is say that if any other process needs CPU, it will get a higher priority than the "nice" processes. As you see this is just some improvement :( because I am sure if users will upload pictures simulataneously the server will definitely crash.*

**My intention is to process all images through the server and not locally via Flash or Java. So if I can't get more server CPU & RAM, I think I need to implement an asynchronous resize job queue through a cron job which gets offered a limited CPU & Memory usage. While an image is processed, the user gets a thumbnail with the info, "your image will be soon available", to stop him from uploading the same image again. That's my basic idea at the moment.**

I work with a PHP framework on a Debian Linux server for this web application. Any help, guiding tips or information resources for such a cron job/job queue/implementation ideas are highly appreciated!!!

Many thanks in advance!

Cheers

Thommy

Comment: Thomas, did you ever work this out? It sounds much like my workflow plans for a new project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the ready made solutions but if you can make a PHP file that can select and upload images from the directory/database - you can setup a worker at www.iron.io and get this task done!

May be implement a REST API to interact remotely is also a good idea. Good luck!